# Remove URLs - Site Removal instead of Web Page removal

Tags: google-search-console, url-removal

Can somebody please advise why `www.example.com/?p=1` comes up with Site Removal rather than Webpage Removal when I submit the URL in Webmaster Tools?

It is the *Hello World!* post that came installed with WordPress and the site description is the old 'we are currently working on our site…".

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a root level query parameter URL (`/?p=`) and not a search engine friendly URL that Google WMT would be able to detect is a directory/page.

You'd be better off setting your permalinks on your website to show friendly URL's such as `/page1` instead of `/?p=1` and then you can specify Google not to index URL's with the query parameter `?p=` in Google WMT.

Answer (score 0):

Some URLS with parameters submitted to the removal tool and returning as site removals seems to be a current bug with the removal tool.

You can redirect it, amend the content, set a canonical tag or add to parameters in webmaster tools, but whatever you do will take time for Google to recrawl and work out the changes.

http://www.seroundtable.com/google-url-removal-tool-bug-18079.html